# Gradle not recognizing plugin tasks from applied child script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would really like to modularize my script into multiple parts (test, default, documentation, android) sections. But I have problems when I try to apply child scripts to parent script...

This is my child script (IDE is not complaining at this point)

```
import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt


task("hello").doLast {
    println("Hello World from plugins! :D")
}


tasks {
    val detekt by existing(Detekt::class) {
        reports {
            html {
                val destination = "$buildDir/detekt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to apply this script to main script:

```
apply(from = "tdd.gradle.kts")
```

I get folowing error:

```
    Script compilation errors:

  Line 01: import io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt
                  ^ Unresolved reference: io

  Line 10:  val detekt by existing(Detekt::class) {
                                   ^ Unresolved reference: Detekt

  Line 11:      reports {
             ^ Unresolved reference: reports

  Line 12:          html {
              ^ Unresolved reference: html
```

How can I solve this problem so that I can apply for example detekt plugin in child script and apply it in to parrent script?

Comment: Can you share your `buildscript` block ?

Comment: @ToYonos: I don't have any since its not necessary because of plugins dsl?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to crack this many ways.  The long and short of it is in Kotlin DSL it is not possible.

UNTESTED:  The method I would try (bc it's the one thing I haven't tried yet) is to do both application of the plugin (in old style) and configuration *all* within your applied script plugin as explicit cross project configuration in a way that does not require `allProjects` nor `subProjects` blocks to be used in your applied script.

You should refer to gradle's current documentation for projects, but generally it takes the form of:

```
project(":foo") {
    // Some configuration here
    apply(plugin = "plugin.id.here.sample-plugin")
    // Then use configuration techniques in the Kotlin DSL guide for configuring when you don't have access to type-safe accessors, small example below
    configure<SamplePluginExtension> {
        // Plugin extension configuration...
    }
}
```

This is because in Kotlin DSL `allProjects` and `subProjects` blocks still do not behave as one would hope/expect (to my knowledge) when defined in applied script plugins.

Although my requirements made it not worth it for me to test the full cross-project/apply plugin technique above, I did get around the `allProjects` and `subProjects` not behaving expectedly (and needing to use `withPlugin<PluginClass>` properly within those blocks as that doesn't seem to work well with the plugin issue above either) by declaring extra-lambas in my applied scripts and then calling them from the target script inside the `allProjects` or `subProjects` configuration blocks they were relevant for.

For example:

*applied.build.gradle.kts*

```
val allProjectsConfiguration by extra { p: Project ->
    // Some project configuration here...
}
```

*build.gradle.kts*

```
//Boilerplate build script dependencies, repositories, and buildscript block as necessary...
val allProjectsConfiguration: (Project) -> Unit by extra
allProjects {
    allProjectsConfiguration(this)
// where `this` is not the host script's project, not the applied script's project (of course), but one of the given projects in *all* of the projects.
```

Some general safety tips for these kinds of lambdas:

- using `p` for the `Project` instance will make sure no developers using it will need to think about what project instance is currently in scope (in the applied script or where it is called).  It also means `project` provided by a enclosing scope at the callsite can still be used.
- heavily consider returning Unit to provide side-effect free usage.  Some plugins have extensions that will auto-configure various elements of a container by simply registering all instances found within the config block of them.  Not supporting chaining implicitly unless absolutely required is the safest option.
- Keep in mind that in a lot of contexts, one cannot rely on kotlin's `T.apply { }` in the standard library here because it will resolve to Gradle's `apply` so if you want to do this (or return to Unit) easily across multiple configuration lambdas it's best to create a little helper function that basically does what apply does in Kotlin, or, do as I have done, build a helper that runs the block it is given and always returns Unit (or some genericized type).

@ToYonos - the gradle suggestion will not work for Kotlin DSL.  I've gotten poor results with this (I used a `classpath` dependency specifically) because gradle will report back that the plugin was never applied and in that same error message it shows that the extension is applied.  My shallow guess is this has to do with byte code and/or having separate class loaders for applied scripts. (sorry I would have put this in a comment on your answer but don't have enough rep)

Answer (score 0):

[From a Gradle core dev](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-access-classes-from-plugin-directly-in-included-script/14721/2) (the situation is pretty analog to yours) :

> Script plugins do not have access to the main buildscript classpath.
>
> You could add a dependency on mycompany.plugin to tests.gradle using
>   the buildscript {} syntax

So basically, use the old `buildscript` syntax and your import should work

Comment: I wll try it in the folowing days. Thank you for referencing the issue on forum. :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds on fuzzyweapon's answer, as I was not able to figure it out until I saw it, kudos!

My answer is based on the Gradle DSL syntax. I'm hoping there's enough detail to glean solutions that apply to the Kotlin DSL as well.

You can solve most problems like this by creating closures that take a Project object parameter instead of putting the build logic directly into your applied scripts (although this works obviously for logic that is independent of the project). For reasons that are not clear to me, creating a new function in a separate script results in the Project object parameter argument always being null. The syntax for a closure is close, and is almost the same as the Java lambda syntax, and the semantics between functions and closures from the caller's perspective are essentially the same (obviously different from inside the external script).

I recently had to solve a similar issue where I wanted to extract some dynamic task generation and cleanup logic into a separate script. This is how I solved it:

1. Move logic to a separate file, in my case I named it env-config.gradle in my project at `$projectDir/gradle/env-config.gradle`
2. Wrap it in a parameterized closure.
3. Fix errors like what you (OP) presented in your question. Most of these issues can be solved using direct imports, like you would do in Java, Kotlin, or directly in Groovy. This can require, specifically for binary plugins, buildscript dependencies as you will see in my full example below.
4. Attach Closure references to the extensions script plugin object.
5. Call closures with the project object as a parameter from the build script where you extracted the logic.

Here is a shortened example based on what I did to solve it, where I define the task creation and task logic then externalize the reference to the closure so it can be called from the script where this script has been applied:

*In `$projectDir/gradle/env-config.gradle`:*

```
def genTasks = { p ->
    def previousServicePropsTask = null
    
    deploymentPlatforms.each {
        def deploymentPlatform = it
        
        deploymentEnvironments.each {
            def deploymentEnv = it
            def propsTaskName = "xslt_${deploymentPlatform}_service_props_$deploymentEnv"
            
            p.logger.info("Creating XSL Transform task: $propsTaskName")
            
            def newServicePropsXslTask = p.tasks.create(
                [name: propsTaskName, type: SaxonXsltTask], {
                    input "${p.projectDir}/dist/config/$deploymentPlatform/config.properties.xml"
                    stylesheet "${p.projectDir}/transforms/build/apply-env-specific-service-properties.xsl"
                    output "${p.projectDir}/config/$deploymentPlatform/$deploymentEnv/config.properties"
                    parameters(envSpecificServicePropsXslTransformParameters[deploymentPlatform][deploymentEnv])
                }
            )
            
            if (previousServicePropsTask != null) {
                newServicePropsXslTask.dependsOn(previousServicePropsTask)
            }
            
            previousServicePropsTask = newServicePropsXslTask
        }
    }
    
    return previousServicePropsTask
}

//... other stuff

ext {
    //Add closure to script plugin extension object
    generateTransformTasks = genTasks
}
```

Then call it in the appropriate scope and phase of the project build script, in my case this is in a custom transform task in the configuration phase:

*In `$projectDir/build.gradle`:*

```
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/env-config.gradle"

task transformConfigurations() {
    def taskDepends = generateTransformTasks(project)
    dependsOn(taskDepends)
}
```

This means of breaking your build scripts up I have found to be quite flexible, and can essentially handle most conceivable cases of wanting to break logic out into separate scripts.

Here is a pared down version of the end product separate build script (which actually happens to even apply a different custom script inside the custom script):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.eerohele:saxon-gradle:0.8.0'
    }
}

import com.github.eerohele.SaxonXsltTask
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.Properties

def deploymentPlatforms = [
    'platX'
]

def deploymentEnvironments = [
    'dev',
    'qa',
    'prod'
]

def envSpecificLog4j2XslTransformParameters = [:]
def envSpecificServicePropsXslTransformParameters = [:]

//Have to use fully-qualified class name here, known issue in Gradle
apply plugin: com.github.eerohele.SaxonPlugin

deploymentPlatforms.each {
    def plat = it
    
    envSpecificLog4j2XslTransformParameters[plat] = [:]
    envSpecificServicePropsXslTransformParameters[plat] = [:]
    
    deploymentEnvironments.each {
        Properties log4j2Props = new Properties()
        Properties serviceProps = new Properties()
        
        serviceProps.load(
            Files.newBufferedReader(
                Paths.get("$projectDir/dist/config/$plat/$it/config.properties"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            )
        )
        
        log4j2Props.load(
            Files.newBufferedReader(
                Paths.get("$projectDir/dist/config/$plat/$it/log4j2.xml.properties"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            )
        )
        
        envSpecificServicePropsXslTransformParameters[plat][it] = serviceProps
        envSpecificLog4j2XslTransformParameters[plat][it] = log4j2Props
    }
}

def genTasks = { p ->
    def previousLog4j2Task = null
    def previousServicePropsTask = null
    
    deploymentPlatforms.each {
        def deploymentPlatform = it
        
        deploymentEnvironments.each {
            def deploymentEnv = it
            def propsTaskName = "xslt_${deploymentPlatform}_service_props_$deploymentEnv"
            p.logger.info("Creating XSL Transform task: $propsTaskName")
            
            def newServicePropsXslTask = p.tasks.create(
                [name: propsTaskName, type: SaxonXsltTask], {
                    input "${p.projectDir}/dist/config/$deploymentPlatform/config.properties.xml"
                    stylesheet "${p.projectDir}/transforms/build/apply-env-specific-service-properties.xsl"
                    output "${p.projectDir}/config/$deploymentPlatform/$deploymentEnv/config.properties"
                    parameters(envSpecificServicePropsXslTransformParameters[deploymentPlatform][deploymentEnv])
                }
            )

            def log4j2XmlTaskName = "xslt_${deploymentPlatform}_service_log4j2_$deploymentEnv"
            p.logger.info("Creating XSL Transform task: $log4j2XmlTaskName")

            def newLog4j2XslTask = p.tasks.create(
                [name: log4j2XmlTaskName, type: SaxonXsltTask], {
                    input "${p.projectDir}/dist/config/$deploymentPlatform/log4j2.xml"
                    stylesheet "${p.projectDir}/transforms/build/apply-env-specific-service-logging.xsl"
                    output "${p.projectDir}/config/$deploymentPlatform/$deploymentEnv/log4j2.xml"
                    parameters(envSpecificLog4j2XslTransformParameters[deploymentPlatform][deploymentEnv])
                }
            )
            
            if (previousServicePropsTask != null) {
                newServicePropsXslTask.dependsOn(previousServicePropsTask)
            }
            if (previousLog4j2Task != null) {
                newLog4j2XslTask.dependsOn(previousLog4j2Task)
            }
            
            previousServicePropsTask = newServicePropsXslTask
            previousLog4j2Task = newLog4j2XslTask
        }
    }
    
    return [
        previousServicePropsTask: previousServicePropsTask,
        previousLog4j2Task: previousLog4j2Task
    ]
}

def cleanupCustomTask = { p ->
    def configsForRemoval = [:]
    def dirsForRemoval = [:]
    
    deploymentPlatforms.each {
        def deploymentPlatform = it
        def generatedPlatformDir = "${p.projectDir}/config/$deploymentPlatform"
        
        deploymentEnvironments.each {
            def deploymentEnv = it
            def distributionName = "$deploymentPlatform${deploymentEnv.capitalize()}"
            def generatedConfigDir = "$generatedPlatformDir/$deploymentEnv"
            def generatedServicePropsConfig = "$generatedConfigDir/config.properties"
            def generatedLog4j2Config = "$generatedConfigDir/lo4j2.xml"
            def generatedDistNameDir = "${p.projectDir}/src/$distributionName"
            def generatedConfigVersionDistDir = "$generatedDistNameDir/dist"
            def generatedConfigVersionText = "$generatedConfigVersionDistDir/config-version.txt"
            def generatedOldConfigVersionText = "$generatedConfigVersionDistDir/version.txt"
            
            configsForRemoval[generatedServicePropsConfig] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedServicePropsConfig))
            configsForRemoval[generatedLog4j2Config] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedLog4j2Config))
            configsForRemoval[generatedConfigVersionText] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedConfigVersionText))
            configsForRemoval[generatedOldConfigVersionText] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedOldConfigVersionText))
            
            dirsForRemoval[generatedConfigDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedConfigDir))
            dirsForRemoval[generatedConfigVersionDistDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedConfigVersionDistDir))
            dirsForRemoval[generatedDistNameDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedDistNameDir))
        }
        
        dirsForRemoval[generatedPlatformDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(generatedPlatformDir))
    }
    
    //Also handle mainConfig, which is not dynamic.
    def mainConfigDistNameDir = "${p.projectDir}/src/mainConfig"
    def mainConfigVersionDistDir = "$mainConfigDistNameDir/dist"
    def mainConfigVersionText = "$mainConfigVersionDistDir/config-version.txt"
    def mainConfigOldVersionText = "$mainConfigVersionDistDir/version.txt"
    
    configsForRemoval[mainConfigVersionText] = Files.exists(Paths.get(mainConfigVersionText))
    configsForRemoval[mainConfigOldVersionText] = Files.exists(Paths.get(mainConfigOldVersionText))
    
    dirsForRemoval[mainConfigVersionDistDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(mainConfigVersionDistDir))
    dirsForRemoval[mainConfigDistNameDir] = Files.exists(Paths.get(mainConfigDistNameDir))
    
    return [
        configsForRemoval: configsForRemoval,
        dirsForRemoval: dirsForRemoval
    ]
}

def genConfigDistTasks = { p, appName ->
    deploymentPlatforms.each {
        def deploymentPlatform = it
        
        deploymentEnvironments.each {
            def deploymentEnv = it
            def distributionName = "$deploymentPlatform${deploymentEnv.capitalize()}"
            
            p.distributions.create(distributionName, {
                baseName = appName
                
                contents {
                    into('config') {
                        from fileTree('src/main/resources').matching {
                                    exclude 'spotbugs-exclusion-filters.xml',
                                        'config/config.properties',
                                        'config/log4j2.xml'
                                }.files
                        from fileTree("config/$deploymentPlatform/$deploymentEnv/log4j2.xml").
                                files
                    }
                }
            })
            
            p.tasks.getByName("${distributionName}DistZip") {
                preserveFileTimestamps = false
                reproducibleFileOrder = true
                archiveBaseName = appName
                includeEmptyDirs = true
                
                dependsOn p.tasks.transformConfigurations
                
                def appVersion = null
                doFirst {
                    appVersion = p.jar.ext.has('version') ? p.jar.ext.version : {
                            apply from: "${p.projectDir}/gradle/version-util.gradle"
                            return getVersionInfo().full
                        }()
                    
                    def distDir = "${p.projectDir}/src/$distributionName/dist"
                    
                    if (Files.notExists(Paths.get(distDir))) {
                        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(distDir))
                    }
                    
                    Files.write(Paths.get("${p.projectDir}/src/$distributionName/dist/config-version.txt"),
                            "$appName-config-$appVersion".toString().getBytes())
                }
                
                doLast {
                    def distAppName = "${p.properties['application.configTitle']}-${appVersion}" +
                            ".${distributionName}.config.${archiveExtension.get()}"
                    
                    p.logger.info(
                      "Fixing archive name, renaming from ${archiveFileName.get()} to $distAppName"
                    )
                    
                    def zabd = "build/distributions"
                    file("$zabd/${archiveFileName.get()}").
                      renameTo(file("$zabd/$distAppName")
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    //Add closures to extension object
    generateConfigurationDistributionTasks = genConfigDistTasks
    cleanUpCustomTrash = cleanupCustomTask
    generateTransformTasks = genTasks
}
```

I know this is a little late but maybe can help someone facing large build files or a need to modularize their build.